# Remove duplicated values from a loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have a loop that outputs `<option>` fields for a `<select>` group. It contains many cities' names for many travel packs that I am publishing. The trick is that I need avoid repeated values.

For instance: I have 4 travel packs departing from Chicago, 5 from Orlando, 3 from Los Angeles e 2 from New York.

So, it outputs:
**Select your city**
Chicago
Chicago
Chicago
Chicago
Orlando
Orlando
Orlando
Orlando
Orlando
Los Angeles
Los Angeles
Los Angeles
New York
New York

I would need to print only one of them!

```
<select name="nDep" id="iDep" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option selected disabled>Outras saídas disponíveis</option>
  <?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'packs',
      'order'         => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if(have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  ?>

<option value="<?php the_field('departures'); ?>"><?php the_field('departures'); ?></option>

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any WordPress-specific way to exclude duplicate-title posts from a query and I'm sure that there are multiple ways to address this. The solution that jumps to mind is to store each post title in an array and then check to see if that title is already there before outputting the post.

Some quick untested code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'packs',
      'order'         => 'ASC',
      'orderby'       => 'title'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // array to store cities
    $unique_cities = array();
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $city = get_the_field('departures');
        // only create option if city hasn't been added yet
        if( ! in_array( $city, $unique_cities ) ) :
            // add city to array so it doesn't repeat
            $unique_cities[] = $city;
    ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?></option>

  <?php
    endif;
  endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Also, note two other minor changes that I think you intended:

- added `orderby` parameter to WP_Query so that cities are listed A-Z.
- fixed first `have_posts()` so it's testing your custom query

Comment: Looks like the city is a custom field and not the post title. So if you need to add it the custom field to the array you should use get_field instead.